# Using a text file to insert multiple Markers on the Google Maps V2

Tags: android, google-maps

In my recent post i was asking for the way to insert multiple Markers on the google map via an ArrayList.
Now i want to use a text file to store (position , title , snippet , icon)

Assuming that i use this code to store every marker:

```
Marker marker1 = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(1.123456, -2.123456))
                .title("Title1")
                .snippet("Snippet1")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon1)));


Marker marker2 = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(3.123456,-4.123456))              
                .title("Title2")
                .snippet("Snippet2")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon2)));
...
```

How to use a text file to store all marker properties and how to use these properties in my map ?

Comment: Save your points in txt file as JSON, and than open file, read json and populate your map.

Comment: You could consider using CSV or TSV if you don't want to bother with deserialising JSON. There are a lot of ways you could do this.